# Hooking Windows API and thread safety

Tags: windows, thread-safety, hook, patch

There are many ways to hook Windows APIs. Inline-hook is one of
them. That is, to replace the first 5 bytes of the function with a
long jump instruction. There are talks and implementations, to
ensure the thread safety of the program, generally they will
suspend all the threads while patching. That is, do something
like this:

```
threads = get_threads();
for (thread in threads) {
    suspend(thread);
}
```

I am very confused, I don't think it's safe. Because threads can
be started or stopped on the fly, while you are in the looping,
things changed. Isn't it (Q1) ?

Since Windows SP2, Windows APIs are hot-patchable. You can also
enable hotpatching on your own image by passing the [/hotpatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173524.aspx)
flag(since VS2008). That is, the compiler ensures that first
instruction of a function is at least two bytes. And put 5 or 6
bytes padding before the function. The padding bytes can be
replaced with a long jump instruction to redirect to the new
version of this function, and the two bytes instruction can be
replaced with a short jump instruction to redirect to the long
jump instruction before it.

Q2: It seems that I don't needed to suspend all the threads while
replacing the first two bytes instruction (Although I don't know
how to suspend all the threads at all) of a hot-patchable
function, is it ?

Q3: Do I need any atomic operation or memory fence or volatile or
something to ensure the replacing is thread-safe ? If so, does
compiler ensure the address of each function is [aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215820/does-msvc-win32-guarantee-function-start-address-is-aligned) ?

Comment: Research your question first, google "windows hotpatching".  The 2nd hit explains why suspending threads doesn't work, the 3rd hit explains how it is implemented.

Comment: @HansPassant Of course. But there're no answers for my questions.

Comment: DeviareInProc is a very good hooking library (and small ) , you can check the techniques involved there. https://github.com/nektra/Deviare-InProc

Comment: @Hernán Thank you, I will do researching on this. I have seen many libraries and I used to write some hooking code, but I am not sure, so I still wanted some exact answers.

Comment: It might be possible to use the fact that no new thread can start when a DllMain function is running.  (Provided the API function you're hooking isn't used during thread initialization, that is.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, that is exactly what I do, I am doing injecting.

Comment: If you're inside DllMain and have successfully suspended all the other threads then I *think* hooking an API should be (relatively) safe unless the API in question is used during thread initialization.  Any pending threads, including any threads injected from outside, won't be able to start up until you've exited DllMain.