# Does MSVC/Win32 guarantee function start address is aligned

Tags: windows, winapi, hotpatching

This question is about hotpatching. The core of hotpatching is to
replace the first two bytes instruction with a two bytes short
jump instruction. Microsoft guarantees the first instruction of a
hotpatchable function is [at least two bytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173507.aspx). Let's call it
[hotpatch point](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110921-00/?p=9583/).

To ensure the replacing operation is an atomic operation, the
address of the hotpatch point must be at least 16-bit aligned,
MSDN says nothing about this.

So my question is: Does MSVC/Win32 guarantee function start
address is aligned ?

Comment: You might want to check out Detours from Microsoft Research. It might have what you want.  More details [here](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/68568/huntusenixnt99.pdf) and [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/#publications).

Comment: @selbie Thank you. But Detours is not designed for hotpatchable function, and the "suspend thread" method it uses is that I do not want to use. Please have a look at 2nd link in my question.

Comment: MS itself relies on this so it must be correct at least for those binaries shipped by MS.